# How do I disable multiple buttons when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function button1() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("button1");
            if (elem.value=="Choose") elem.value = "Selected";
            else elem.value = "Choose";
        }
        function button2() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("button2");
            if (elem.value=="Choose") elem.value = "Selected";
            else elem.value = "Choose";
        }
        function button3() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("button3");
            if (elem.value=="Choose") elem.value = "Selected";
            else elem.value = "Choose";
        }
        function button4() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("button4");
            if (elem.value=="Choose") elem.value = "Selected";
            else elem.value = "Choose";
        }
        function button5() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("button5");
            if (elem.value=="Choose") elem.value = "Selected";
            else elem.value = "Choose";
        }

    </script>
```

How do disable all the buttons if I select one button. Do I have to disable all the buttons one by one or is there a way to do all the buttons.

Comment: Your JavaScript seems too old. We don't use `type="text/javascript"` now-a-days. Do you have a HTML as well? Can you use jQuery on this?

Comment: In addition to what @PraveenKumarPurushothaman says --  You can look into giving your buttons a "class" and using `getElementByClassName("class_name")` -- This will allow you to perform an action on many elements at once.

Comment: I don't know how to use jQuery. I was searching how to make buttons using html and css and one of code I saw included type="text/javascript".

Comment: You should share your *pertinent* HTML with us as well.

Comment: Can you explain what pertinent is I'm still really new with html and the vocab

Comment: @Kriskevz23 Check out my answer and tell me if my understanding of your problem is right?

Comment: @Kriskevz23 The associated and relevant HTML of your JavaScript on which it's gonna be acted is pertinent HTML.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, with whatever you have given, maybe you're looking for something like a radio button. I am using Bootstrap and jQuery - it's much easier than vanilla JavaScript to achieve something that you're trying to do:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).prop("disabled", false).addClass("active");
    $("p").text("You have clicked on button #" + $(this).data("id") + ".");
    $(this).text("Selected");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="p-5">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-1" data-id="1">Choose 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-2" data-id="2">Choose 2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-3" data-id="3">Choose 3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-4" data-id="4">Choose 4</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-5" data-id="5">Choose 5</button>
  <p id="status" class="py-3"></p>
</div>
```

On clicking of any button above, the respective button will be activated and the others will be disabled.

#### Resetting...

**Option One: Using the same button!**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".btn").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
      $("p").text("");
      $(this).text("Choose " + $(this).data("id"));
    } else {
      $(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).prop("disabled", false).addClass("active");
      $("p").text("You have clicked on button #" + $(this).data("id") + ".");
      $(this).text("Selected");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="p-5">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-1" data-id="1">Choose 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-2" data-id="2">Choose 2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-3" data-id="3">Choose 3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-4" data-id="4">Choose 4</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-5" data-id="5">Choose 5</button>
  <p id="status" class="py-3"></p>
</div>
```

**Option Two: Using a Cancel Button**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
    $(".btn-primary").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).prop("disabled", false).addClass("active");
    $(".btn-info").prop("disabled", false);
    $("p").text("You have clicked on button #" + $(this).data("id") + ".");
    $(this).text("Selected");
  });
  $(".btn-info").click(function () {
    $(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
    $("p").text("");
    $(".btn-primary").text(function () {
      return "Choose " + $(this).data("id");
    });
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="p-5">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-1" data-id="1">Choose 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-2" data-id="2">Choose 2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-3" data-id="3">Choose 3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-4" data-id="4">Choose 4</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button-5" data-id="5">Choose 5</button>
  <p id="status" class="py-3"></p>
  <button class="btn btn-info" disabled>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I hope the above two solutions are something that you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. Is it also possible to go backward so if I click on selected it goes back to choose and activate the other buttons? Or do I have to add a cancel button?

Comment: Yes, clicking on the same button - we can make it do.

Comment: @Kriskevz23 Would you like to kindly refresh the page and check the updated answers? Let me know what you feel?

Comment: Yes this is perfect thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Always avoid repetitive code.**

By *"disabling all buttons"*, I guess you mean set their value back to "Choose".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonBehavior(num) {
        // reset all buttons
        let i=1;
        while(document.getElementById("button"+i)!==null) {
             document.getElementById("button"+i).value = 'Choose';
             i++;
        }
        // set selected button
        var elem = document.getElementById("button"+num);
        if (elem.value=="Choose") elem.value = "Selected";
        else elem.value = "Choose";
    }
</script>
```